# Merging two loglog plot in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

given the following set of data:

```
0.0010339964703699645   1.1335006374746552e-7        0.0036126270484542334      
0.0012221213681267867   1.9921394136413835e-7         0.005261243901795814      
0.0014205289558535598   3.288567819970283e-7          0.007425886368281838      
0.0017072805793891044   5.09897629791369e-7       0.010481131341546832      
0.001984452250029774    8.417246932261471e-7          0.014793400915475614      
0.0023455026862141174   0.000001389495494373136       0.020235896477251224      
0.002772242492080673    0.0000022937401556835766      0.028561585549968214      
0.003276623164863039    0.0000037864418582867756      0.04031272694269899       
0.003808572703579145    0.000005870937850692427       0.05344304028586673       
0.004426882588756425    0.000009691579392800477       0.07085004591866341       
0.005320504478191538    0.000015026946780037802       0.09999999999999795       
0.006184271765580915    0.000024806061902520164       0.13679002274643795       
0.00743264474795339     0.0000435969173544848         0.20555363918508876       
0.008784937113875308    0.00006759770831018738        0.2901249202026803        
0.010041876641771868    0.0001115883992507748         0.3727593720314877        
0.011868891598451578    0.00018420699693267163        0.5261243901795244        
0.014264776540746428    0.0003040837394100148         0.7196856730011411        
0.0168601041894875      0.0005019729006676898         1.0157871652296924        
0.019927624696285583    0.0008286427728546826         1.4793400915475645        
0.023553248637906678    0.0013679002274643991         2.0235896477251267        
0.027377045003188133    0.0021209508879201926         2.768068739417809     
0.03182162276758441     0.0035012061856667213         3.669660188580873     
0.04674029725500457     0.012258444754550964          7.783169035335985     
0.062101694189156224    0.02442053094548645       13.679002274643823        
0.07158292449880059     0.04159562163071843       18.134408785428295        
0.08531678524172823     0.0665471179633392        27.25047957060815     
0.10083928648856323     0.10985411419875572       37.27593720314892     
0.11721022975334817     0.17033053754470567       49.417133613237674        
0.13623894453468574     0.28117686979742307       65.51285568595429     
0.16102620275609408     0.46415888336127725       95.40954763499826     
0.1935313656264482      0.7662204546142304        138.9495494373119     
0.22874238366617797     1.2648552168552907        190.0691202813751     
0.27035968002353816     2.222996482526191         268.2695795279694     
0.31425172980765415     3.2374575428176398        366.96601885808883        
0.3714265618637218      5.34430402858675          501.97290066768466        
0.4390037596367272      8.822227063126444         708.5004591866399     
0.5188759253192368      14.563484775012384        969.1579392800378     
0.5931161449307741      23.29951810515367         1325.7113655900946        
0.7248599145008832      39.68619443383435         1930.6977288832318        
0.828572105824921       61.53407071116586         2559.54792269951      
0.9958297992232203      101.5787165229707         3612.627048453646     
1.1770106683368593      178.52567354823375        5098.976297913632     
1.41460506489842        276.8068739417843         7425.88636828145      
1.6170052641696395      456.9450168789167         9844.581958011371     
1.9112025450223642      708.5004591866457         13051.074191219035        
2.221480309984754       1169.5726687403355        17852.567354823266        
2.6256555351043787      1930.6977288832436        24420.53094548635     
3.1556771051918786      3187.141611585059         33404.84983513217     
3.667991428805581       5428.6754393238425        45694.50168789148     
4.335344299236616       8157.641691281789         66547.11796333866     
5.124115079800981       14337.141946186151        91029.81779915153     
6.158482110660273       23667.35144725228         136790.02274643906        
7.15829244988006        39069.39937054605         199213.9413641371     
8.182493376519213       56898.660290182816        272504.7957060832     
9.671212897295495       99999.99999999959         384621.9041536204
```

I want to use gnuplot to do a log-log plot of the  data using atomic units in the left y axys and using another units in the right y axys. Attemting to do so using  the command:

```
 p 'Freq_vs_Intensity_TDPT_AU.dat' u 1:2 w l, '' u 1:($2*3.51e16) w l axes x1y2
```

Produces two lines that are not superimposed as I want. How can I do this log-log plot?

Comment: Since version 5.0 this should be a use case for `set link`, e.g. `set link y2 via 3.51e16*y inverse y/3.51e16`, but that doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should the rescaled column represent the same data expressed in different units, then there is probably no need to plot it twice. One could merely set the corresponding `y2range` and show the `y2` axis, e.g.,

```
fac = 3.51e16
ymin = 1E-7
ymax = 1E5
set yr [ymin:ymax]
set y2r [ymin*fac:ymax*fac]

set ytics nomirror
set y2tics

p 'Freq_vs_Intensity_TDPT_AU.dat' u 1:2 w l
#, '' u 1:($2*3.51e16) w l axes x1y2
```